# Webscraping returns Variables instead of actual values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from https://sunshinetour.com/stats/ however, if I try to access the anchor tags, it returns a variable instead of the actual value.  This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://sunshinetour.com/stats/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for player in soup.find_all('a', class_='player-name-table'):
    print(player.text)
```

And this is the result I obtain:

```
{{value.name}}
```

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to scrape table on that page call the below api (returns a json)

```
page = requests.get('https://sunshinetour.com/api/sst/cache/sst/219S/219S-ooms-oom-FT.json?randomadd=1575877373100')
for item in page.json().get('oom').get('oom_entry'):
   print(item.get('name'),'\t',
        item.get('nationality'),'\t',
        item.get('oom_value'),'\t',
        item.get('tournaments_played'))
```

```
Daniel van Tonder    RSA     1,511,262.56    13
Branden Grace        RSA     1,332,272.40    1
Charl Schwartzel     RSA     1,332,272.40    1
MJ Viljoen           RSA     825,268.65      16
Jaco Ahlers          RSA     773,652.24      13
Thriston Lawrence    RSA     739,455.53      14
JC Ritchie           RSA     665,548.53      11
......
```

Comment: Good sir, you are an absolute legend.  Apologies, I only started python yesterday lol.

Comment: How would I store this in an excel file though?  Would I need to use the pandas library?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you very much.  Now I need to figure out how to access the API for all pages lol